# How do I represent date range for months that donot have 31 days in c#?

Tags: c#, datetime, datarow

I want to find the leaves taken by an employee in a month. 
The code works perfectly for all the dates. 
Now, if I want to find the leaves taken by the employee in January, the range is:

```
DateTime first = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.Month + "01" + DateTime.Now.Year);
DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.Month + "31" + DateTime.Now.Year);
```

The problem is that some months do not have 31 days. Is there an easy way with which I could assign the variables From and To the range. An error would be given when the months's Feburary or April because they donot have 31 days.

The code for executing the search is :

```
returnedRows = LeaveDS.Tables["Leave"].Select("LeaveDate >= #" + first + "# AND LeaveDate <= #" + end + "#");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
DateTime end = first.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month)
```

it'll give you the days in a month.

Answer (score 2):

Use `DateTime.DaysInMonth(int year, int month)`

```
        int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(2012, 2);
        int days2 = DateTime.DaysInMonth(2011, 2);
```

output:

```
 days = 29
 days2 = 28
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the number of days in a month by `DateTime.DaysInMonth(year,month)`, and use this as basis for your query.

The alternative is to use the first of each month but alter your select query to be less than the end date.

```
DateTime first = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.Month + "01" + DateTime.Now.Year);
DateTime end = first.AddMonths(1); // Becomes 01 of next month

returnedRows = LeaveDS.Tables["Leave"].Select("LeaveDate >= #" + first + "# AND LeaveDate < #" + end + "#");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a great method to get the days in a month, it's called [DateTime.DaysInMonth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
DateTime end = new DateTime(first.Year, first.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(first.Year, first.Month);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var enddate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
DateTime end = new DateTime(enddate.Year,enddate.Month,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, if you're using .NET 3.5 or greater Linq-To-DataSet will simplify and improve the code:

```
int month = 2; // f.e. for february
var currentCalendar = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;
int daysInMonth = currentCalendar.GetDaysInMonth(month);
DateTime start = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, month, 1);
DateTime end = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, month, daysInMonth);
var filteredRows = LeaveDS.Tables["Leave"].AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.Field<DateTime>("LeaveDate").Date >= start
             && r.Field<DateTime>("LeaveDate").Date <= end );
// use ToArray for an array, CopyToDataTable for a DataTable etc.
```

Comment: This code looks really interesting but I'm not really good at LINQ so I won't use it. 
Thanks anyways